# Sequence subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Wondering about this exercise:

1)The sequence subset $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such as $\forall n \ \in \mathbb{N^*}, u_{n+2}=u_n+u_{n-1}$ is it a E-subspace ?

$0=(0)_n \ \in \ F $ because 0=0+0 but as n is defined in $\mathbb{N*}$, I'm not sure it is correct.

.Let $\lambda \ , \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ et $(u_n),(v_n) \ \in F$. We have

$\lambda(u_n)+\mu (v_n)=(\lambda u_n + \mu v_n)$ and

$\lambda u_{n+2}+\mu v_{n+2}=\lambda(u_n+u_{n-1})+\mu(v_n+v_{n-1})=(\lambda u_n+\mu v_n)+(\lambda u_{n-1}+\mu u_{n-1})$. Thus $\lambda(u_n)+\mu(v_n) \ \in F$ and F is a subspace of E.

Is it the right way to proceed ?
Thanks

Comment: You have shown that all the conditions for it being a subspace is satisfied and the derivation looks correct so well done.